# Unmet dependency with tzdata & tzdata-java in 12.04

Tags: 12.04, apt, dpkg, dependencies

I'm a bit stuck with package dependency. I'm not really sure how I got in to this mess but the current state:
If I want to do any install using *apt-get install* or *apt-get upgrade* it gets stuck on a dependency loop with tzdata & tzdata-java.

So I did *apt-get autoremove* for some clean-up:

```
@webserver1:~$ sudo apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
tzdata-java : Depends: tzdata (= 2016g-0ubuntu0.12.04) but 2016j-0ubuntu0.12.04 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

So I did *apt-get autoremove -f*

```
@webserver1:~$ sudo apt-get autoremove -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
 tzdata-java
The following packages will be upgraded:
   tzdata-java
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 62 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 126 kB of archives.
After this operation, 3,072 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
Get:1 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main tzdata-java     all 2016j-0ubuntu0.12.04 [126 kB]
Fetched 126 kB in 0s (2,076 kB/s)
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of tzdata-java:
tzdata-java depends on tzdata (= 2016g-0ubuntu0.12.04); however:
Version of tzdata on system is 2016j-0ubuntu0.12.04.
dpkg: error processing tzdata-java (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup  error from a previous failure.
Errors were encountered while processing:
  tzdata-java
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Then I tried *dpkg --configure -a* :

```
@webserver1:~$ dpkg --configure -a
dpkg: error: requested operation requires superuser privilege
logwise@webserver1:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of tzdata-java:
tzdata-java depends on tzdata (= 2016g-0ubuntu0.12.04); however:
Version of tzdata on system is 2016j-0ubuntu0.12.04.
dpkg: error processing tzdata-java (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
tzdata-java
```

Can I manually install this missing 2016g version together with 2016j to break this dependency circle ? If yes, how do I proceed ?
Please advise...

As requested:

*sudo apt-cache policy tzdata*

```
tzdata:
Installed: 2016j-0ubuntu0.12.04
Candidate: 2016j-0ubuntu0.12.04
Version table:
*** 2016j-0ubuntu0.12.04 0
    500 nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
    500 security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main amd64 Packages
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
  2012b-1 0
    500 nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
```

And *sudo apt-cache policy tzdata-java*

```
tzdata-java:
Installed: 2016g-0ubuntu0.12.04
Candidate: 2016j-0ubuntu0.12.04
Version table:
 2016j-0ubuntu0.12.04 0
    500 nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
    500 security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main amd64 Packages
 *** 2016g-0ubuntu0.12.04 0
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
   2012b-1 0
    500 nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
```

Also *apt-cache showpkg tzdata-java*

```
Reverse Depends:
openjdk-6-jre-headless,tzdata-java
openjdk-7-jre-headless,tzdata-java 2012e-0ubuntu0.12.04.1
openjdk-6-jre-headless,tzdata-java
openjdk-7-jre-headless,tzdata-java
openjdk-6-jre-headless,tzdata-java
Dependencies:
2016j-0ubuntu0.12.04 - tzdata (5 2016j-0ubuntu0.12.04)
2016g-0ubuntu0.12.04 - tzdata (5 2016g-0ubuntu0.12.04)
2012b-1 - tzdata (5 2012b-1)
Provides:
2016j-0ubuntu0.12.04 - tzdata-java:i386
2016g-0ubuntu0.12.04 - tzdata-java:i386
2012b-1 - tzdata-java:i386
```

.

Comment: I think it's suggesting you should run `sudo apt-get -f install` **not** `sudo apt-get autoremove -f` . Regardless, I'd suggest running `sudo apt-get update` first

Comment: Did apt-get update first. Then **apt-get -f install**  . Exactly same output as the **autoremove -f** command above.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the output of `apt-cache policy tzdata` and `apt-cache policy tzdata-java`.

Comment: Well, looks like version `2016j-0ubuntu0.12.04` of `tzdata-java` is available, so let's try to install it: `sudo apt-get install tzdata-java=2016j-0ubuntu0.12.04`.

Comment: Executed `sudo apt-get install tzdata-java=2016j-0ubuntu0.12.04` , output -  `dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of tzdata-java:  tzdata-java depends on tzdata (= 2016g-0ubuntu0.12.04); however: Version of tzdata on system is 2016j-0ubuntu0.12.04. `

Answer (score 1):

**What's Happening**: You have a *version conflict*.

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of tzdata-java:
tzdata-java depends on tzdata (= 2016g-0ubuntu0.12.04); however:
Version of tzdata on system is 2016j-0ubuntu0.12.04.
```

Let's look at which version of tzdata is in the Ubuntu repos:

```
$ rmadison tzdata
 tzdata | 2012b-1              | precise          | source, all
 tzdata | 2016j-0ubuntu0.12.04 | precise-security | source, all
 tzdata | 2016j-0ubuntu0.12.04 | precise-updates  | source, all
```

So far, so good You are clearly running 12.04, and `tzdata` is clearly the latest available version.

Now let's see if your version of `tzdata-java` matches 12.04

```
$ rmadison tzdata-java
tzdata-java | 2012b-1              | precise          | all
tzdata-java | 2016j-0ubuntu0.12.04 | precise-security | all
tzdata-java | 2016j-0ubuntu0.12.04 | precise-updates  | all
```

Uh-oh. The latest `tzdata-java` is 2016j, not 2016g.

**The Problem**: Your `tzdata-java` is either from some non-ubuntu source, or (more likely) it's required by some other non-Ubuntu software on your system.

**One Solution**: Uninstall `tzdata-java` and all software that requires it. That software is *no longer compatible* with your release of Ubuntu. If you wish, you can ping the upstream source of that software - perhaps they have a compatible version available.

```
sudo apt-get remove tzdata-java
```

Be sure to read the list of removed packages carefully. Refuse the removal and return here if you have questions about what will be removed.

Comment: Instead of making assumptions about the state of installed packages on the system, ask for the necessary clarifications in comments.

Comment: Added the detailed output on dependency and source to the question. The uninstall obviously trips on openjdk-6-jre-headless . I'm checking what the impact of uninstall will be on the app running on this webserver.

Comment: @fkraiem assumptions removed. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Seemed to have fixed it using:

Downloading the tzdata 2016g version it was complaining about:

```
wget "https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tzdata/2016g-0ubuntu0.12.04/+build/10969235/+files/tzdata_2016g-0ubuntu0.12.04_all.deb"
```

Installing it:

```
sudo dpkg -i tzdata_2016g-0ubuntu0.12.04_all.deb
```

Then trigger a update

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Do a clean-up (output told me tzdata & tzdata-java are now all fine on 2016g version):

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Then doing a full upgrade:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

This last step got everything back up to the 2016j version

```
@webserver1:~$ sudo apt-cache policy tzdata
tzdata:
Installed: 2016j-0ubuntu0.12.04
Candidate: 2016j-0ubuntu0.12.04
Version table:
*** 2016j-0ubuntu0.12.04 0
    500 nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
    500 security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main amd64 Packages
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
 2012b-1 0
    500 nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages

 @webserver1:~$ sudo apt-cache policy tzdata-java
 tzdata-java:
 Installed: 2016j-0ubuntu0.12.04
 Candidate: 2016j-0ubuntu0.12.04
 Version table:
 *** 2016j-0ubuntu0.12.04 0
    500 nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
    500 security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main amd64 Packages
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
 2012b-1 0
    500 nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
```